# Setting values at set steps on form Slider

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created a form slider in HTML5. At the moment it shows the numeric value according to the step settings of the slider. I would like to display the value alongside a sentence of text at specific steps of the slider.

**My code as it  now:**

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValue(newValue)
{
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a swicth/case like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showValue(newValue)
        {
            var sentence = "";

            switch (newValue) {
                case "10":
                    sentence = ": Your sentence for step 10";
                    break;
                case "25":
                    sentence = ": Another sentence for step 25";
                    break;
            }
            document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newValue + sentence;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just one more question if I may, below the slider I have a bootstrap button line. Is there a way that i can pass the selected 'step' as a URL variable so that I can retrieve it on the following pages.

Comment: If your button GETs a page, you could pass your variable as a querystring.

Add this after the document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newValue + sentence; :

var current_link = document.getElementById("my_button").href;
document.getElementById("my_button").href = current_link + "?step="  + newValue;

Answer (score 1):

Simply add in an `if` or `switch` statement:

```js
function showValue(newValue)
{
    // If our passed in value is equal to 50, set the HTML
    if (newValue == 50)
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
    // Otherwise clear the HTML
    else
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML='';
}
```

```js
function showValue(newValue)
{
    switch (newValue) {
        case 50:
            document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById("range").innerHTML='';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't aggree with the answers here. In most cases it is bad practice to place text content inside of your JS. Second, if the text you want to show is an important descriptive part for the range's value, you should use a datalist to make it accessible.

This means your HTML could look something like this:

```
<div class="range-output">
    <label for="range">label</label>
    <input id="range" name="range" list="range-list" type="range" value="0" step="10" max="50" />
    <datalist id="range-list">
        <select>
            <option value="0" label="low"></option>
            <option value="20" label="middle"></option>
            <option value="50" label="high"></option>
        </select>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

And your JS (I'm using jQuery here), could look like this:

```
$('div.range-output').each(function () {
    var range = $('input[type="range"]', this);
    var output = $('<span class="output" />').appendTo(this);
    var updateOutput = function () {
        var val = range.prop('value');
        var valLabel = $(range.prop('list')).find('option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('label');
        output.html(valLabel || val);
    };
    range.on('input', updateOutput).each(updateOutput);
});
```

To answer your second question: input[type="range"] is a normal form control. You can simply name it and put it inside a form attribute. And instead of using anchors with button style use an button[type="submit"] and you are done. In case you can not put the button and/or the input[type="range"] inside of a form. You can associate them with a form using the form attribute.

Here is a simple fiddle, that showcases the code above: